# How Can I integrate Number Mask within Autocomplete Material-UI component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

We are using [react-number-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format) (###)-###-####' for phone number formatting and Autocomplete component from @material-ui. So, how to integrate react-number-format within a Autocomplete component so that when the user searches for the phone number for eg. '1234567899' it gets auto converted to this format '(123)-456-7899'.

Have implemented the code as below. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
    <Autocomplete
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  classes={{
    option: classes.option
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
  )}
/>
```

<NumberFormat formate = '(###)-###-####' mask="_" prefix={'01'} />;